# Sprite or image under text unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How do I make green sprite or image under number 3 (text)? Text before number and after can be changed.

[image: Example]

Comment: Sprites are not made in unity. You need  to have the sprite already, and change to another sprite when you need to change number. Unity is a game engine so meant to handle the sprites, not to make them.

Comment: I mean to place the sprite under certain text. Sorry.

Comment: What have you tried, what is not working? Please show your code.

Answer (score 0):

Your sprite should already be in a gameobject that has a canvas component.
In the canvas you need to use a Text mesh component, and set your text settings.
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TextMesh.html